# How to access elements in laravel using pgsql as database?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I am currently learning laravel with pgsql as the defaut database.
I was reading the laravel tutorial online and I am in the chapter "Working with database".
I copy pasted the code for retrieving records but it doesn't work so I am assuming that it is probably because the tutorial uses MySQL while I'm using postgres.
I modified the code a bit and ended up with these:
[StudentController.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEbdx.png)
[stud_view.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHCom.png)

All I'm getting is a table with headers but it's empty.
I noticed that as I add more tuples in the student table the table being showed by the stud_view is getting bigger but still empty so the Studentontroller must be correct right? The **$user->id** line of code must then be wrong. Well how do I access the elements then? By the way my student table has attributes name and id only. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my mistake was the filename! I should've saved it as stud_view.blade.php After doing so it worked. I don't understand why though because I thought blade was just used for styling.